# Why new File("c:\\a") not equals new File("c:\\a","\\")?

Tags: java, file

these equal to each other:

```
new File("c:\\a")
new File("c:\\a\\")
new File("c:\\a","")
new File("c:\\a\\","")
```

but 
    `new File("c:\\a","\\")` not equals to them

but 
    `new File("c:\\a","\\b")` equals to `new File("c:\\a","b")`

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`equals()` - [Compares two abstract pathnames lexicographically](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#compareTo%28java.io.File%29).

The following prints make it clear, that this have not the same path.

```
System.out.println(new File("c:\\a").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(new File("c:\\a\\").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(new File("c:\\a","").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(new File("c:\\a\\","").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(new File("c:\\a","\\").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(new File("c:\\a","\\b").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(new File("c:\\a","b").getAbsolutePath());
```

output

```
c:\a
c:\a
c:\a
c:\a
c:\a\
c:\a\b
c:\a\b
```

Answer (score 2):

The [JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for `java.io.File` should make this clear.

```
File(File parent, String child)
          Creates a new File instance from a parent abstract pathname and a child pathname string.
File(String pathname)
          Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string into an abstract pathname.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Java, but isnt it because "c:\a" is a file, and "\" is a directory?

Comment: For Java, at least without the inclusion of the new IO stuff with JDK7, a directory is a File object with isDirectory flag set to true. The javadoc, however, explains that files are compared LEXICOgRAPHICALLY, which means that as long as their paths are the same, the Files are going to be the same. You can override that behavior, of course, by implementing your own Comparator.